# CodeIgniter: no CSS applied from external file

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

The CSS code in my `<CI root>/css/menus.css` is not applied.  The file is displayed without CSS.

Here is my header template:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>air de java</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" 
        href = "<?= base_url('css/menus.css'); ?>" media="all">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>AIR DE JAVA</h1>
        ...
```

When I replace the PHP call in `href` attribute with "http://localhost/fil/index.html" I get a 404 error (`index.html` is a dummy file with a h1 tag).

I have installed the url plugin.  In my controller, I have:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

The `base_url()` function returns the expected URL ("http://localhost/fil/css/menus.css")

It could worth notice that I am using XAMPP on Windows, and here is the redirection part of my `httpd.conf`:

```
<Directory "C:/Users/lolve/Dropbox/air de java/air_de_java_appliperso2">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And the alias:

```
ScriptAlias /fil/ "C:/Users/lolve/Dropbox/air de java/air_de_java_appliperso2/"
```

I spent time on searching on the net but without success.

**EDIT:**

CodeIgniter has a strange behaviour: it seems to head to old versions of my files.  I saw it because the click on a button calls a Javascript function, whose an old version contained this line `alert("enable");` and now I no more have this line, but the button is still there, and click on it triggers the chrome's notification ... Very strange. I tried to hit CTRL+F5 to bypass chrome's cache, but without success. From explorer is the same: the problem comes from CodeIgniter. But why?  Also, Chrome's debugger pointed out the fact that there is an error with the load of `menus.css`:
[image: plz have a look at this]

**EDIT**

I had a look at Apache logs, and here is what I found:

> [Sat Feb 23 18:58:59.817271 2019] [win32:error] [pid 13940:tid 1900] [client ::1:50408] AH02102: C:/Users/lolve/Dropbox/air de java/air_de_java_appliperso2/css/menus.css is not executable; ensure interpreted scripts have "#!" or "'!" first line, referer: http://localhost/fil/
>   [Sat Feb 23 18:58:59.817271 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 13940:tid 1900] (9)Bad file descriptor: [client ::1:50408] AH01222: don't know how to spawn child process: C:/Users/lolve/Dropbox/air de java/air_de_java_appliperso2/css/menus.css, referer: http://localhost/fil/

Comment: _"when I replace the php call in href attribute with "http://localhost/fil/index.html" I get a 404 error. (index.html is a dummy file with a h1 tag)"_ ... What do you mean by that?

Comment: sorry, it wasn't totally true: in my browser, if I try to access to "http://localhost/fil/css/menus.css " I get an error 500 and independently of this, if I try to replace in my header.php file the href (with php call) by href='http://localhost/fil/css/menus.css' nothing happens, I get the page without css applied. now it should be clearer.

Comment: Okay. So checking through your folder structure, where exactly do you have your `menus.css` saved?

Comment: it's in the <root>/css folder, root being the directory containing the codeigniter's application and system directories

Comment: Okay. From your XAMPP's `httpd.conf` file, what value do you have for `DocumentRoot` ?

Comment: it's DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs" but I have an alias : ScriptAlias /fil/ "C:/Users/lolve/Dropbox/air de java/air_de_java_appliperso2/"

Comment: Well, I really do not know what you are trying to achieve by changing the default values in your `httpd.conf`. I'll suggest you return the default values and check again. `<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">` and `ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/xampp/cgi-bin/"`

Comment: it's because the site is located in a dropbox directory, so I added a "directory" part heading to the dropbox directory, and an alias, "/fil", heading to this directory. I found it in a tutorial and seemed to be natural(natural purpose of aliases?).

Comment: @SamuelAsor : plz have a look, the problem definitely comes from codeIgniter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not mentioned why you are using that `ScriptAlias`, but that is the problem.  The Apache log record you quote shows:

> ... menus.css is not executable; ... referer: http://localhost/fil/

So you visited `http://localhost/fil/`, and Apache tried to *execute* your CSS, which of course makes no sense.  Why is Apache trying to do that?  Because of this:

```
ScriptAlias /fil/ "C:/Users/lolve/Dropbox/air de java/air_de_java_appliperso2/"
```

According to [the Apache documentation for `ScriptAlias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#scriptalias):

> The ScriptAlias directive has the additional effect of marking the target directory as containing only CGI scripts.

So Apache thinks that anything inside the `fil/` directory is an executable CGI script.  When you try to access `fil/css/menus.css`, Apache thinks it is some kind of CGI script, and tries to execute it.  That won't work - Apache should just send that file as text to the browser, which can parse it and use it to style the page.

Do you have some specific reason to use that `ScriptAlias`?  You should not need it for a normal Codeigniter installation, you'd only use that for some specific (and not very usual) requirement.  Get rid of it if you can, and restart Apache.  If you do need it, you'll need to change the directory it points at to get Codeigniter to work.

Comment: thank you, I found this answer yesterday and was ready to write it now but you were quicker. thank you anyway!